# javascript regex for string of length N that contains at least one letter x in it

Tags: javascript, regex

So it's easy to match for at least one character or to match a character of a certain length in a string, but I'm trying to match at least one character in a string of a certain length. Another way to think of it would be the negation of having no character x for a sequence of N letters, which I think would just be /^[^x]{N}$/. I'm using this in a query, and though could use the negation regex would prefer the former. I'm also just curious as to how one would do it.

Comment: Your question seems to contradict your title...? In any case, surely just save yourself the hassle and check the length with `.length` and the "x" character with `.indexOf()` (or a simple regex if necessary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
(?=\w*x)\w{5,}
```

The ?= is a positive lookahead

Edit:  jonahb correctly pointed out a correction.  My previous (incorrect) suggestion was:

```
(?=.*x)\w{5,}
```

Comment: That would match "aaaaa x". Instead: (?=\w*x)\w{5,}

Answer (score 4):

### Patterns with no string length requirement:

At least one `"X"`:

```js
if /X/.test(text) {
     // At least one X.
}
```

Exactly one `"X"`:

```js
if /^[^X]*X[^X]*$/.test(text) {
     // Exactly one X.
}
```

3 or more `"X"`:

```
if /^(?:[^X]*X){3}/.test(text) {
    // 3 or more X.
}
```

From 3 to 5 `"X"` (no more, no less):

```
if /^[^X]*(?:X[^X]*){3,5}$/.test(text) {
    // From 3 to 5 X.
}
```

### Adding a minimum string length requirement:

At least one `"X"` and length >= 9:

```js
if /^(?=[\S\s]{9})[^X]*X/.test(text) {
     // At least one X and length >= 9.
}
```

Exactly one `"X"` and length >= 9:

```js
if /^(?=[\S\s]{9})[^X]*X[^X]*$/.test(text) {
     // Exactly one X and length >= 9.
}
```

3 or more `"X"` and length >= 9:

```
if /^(?=[\S\s]{9})(?:[^X]*X){3}/.test(text) {
    // 3 or more X and length >= 9.
}
```

From 3 to 5 `"X"` (no more, no less) and length >= 9:

```
if /^(?=[\S\s]{9})[^X]*(?:X[^X]*){3,5}$/.test(text) {
    // From 3 to 5 X and length >= 9.
}
```

### Adding a string length range requirement:

From 3 to 5 `"X"` (no more, no less) and length from 9 to 15:

```
if /^(?=[\S\s]{9,15}$)[^X]*(?:X[^X]*){3,5}$/.test(text) {
    // From 3 to 5 X and length from 9 to 15.
}
```

Hopefully you get the idea and can take it from here.

Note also that there is more than one way to do this but as you can see, regex can easily handle this type of chore. (Assuming you "speak" regex language itself.) Note also that the DOT wildcard is not used anywhere in these expressions (although most folks use this a lot, its use is rarely needed.). However, the length requirement subpatterns (e.g. `^(?=[\S\s]{9,15}$)`) *do* make use of the `[\S\s]` which is equivalent to the dot-matches-newline modified DOT under JavaScript.)

### Mastering Regular Expressions

To thoroughly understand these patterns I highly recommend reading: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) Once you have read and studied this book, problems like this become *child's play!*

Happy regexing!